# PDF Presentation (Beamer LaTeX / Adobe Acrobat Reader) on Android tablet

Tags: tablet, pdf, adobe-reader

I have just received my Nexus 10 - my first Android tablet!

I bought the tablet partly for giving presentations. My presentations are created by using the LaTeX package "beamer", which produces PDF files. Acrobat Reader (on PC) has a presentation mode that works perfectly well for all purposes, but I have trouble finding this functionality in the Android version.

There is a full-page display functionality in Adobe's app, but it has some animation for the page transitions. This means that "revealing" of new content (which is implemented by having successive slides that are identical except for the parts that are being revealed) will not work. This is one of the main functionalities that I want in my PDF presentations, and I seem to be unable to find any setting that would turn off the animation.

I have tried searching and the results I got were either about general PDF viewers or PowerPoint (etc) presentation apps. Rather than trying all the different PDF/presentation apps there are, I was hoping that someone might already be using their tablet in this manner, and would be able to help me out.

I have also tried ezPDF reader, but I did not find any presentation-style display at all. So my question is this:

**Is there any way to do Beamer PDF presentation on Android tablets conveniently?**

(3rd-party app is accepted, and ideally it should work with standard bluetooth presentation devices)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575)

Comment: I think this question is fine for this site. There is a well-defined problem to be solved. However, @mathstribble, you should probably [edit] out your request for "best app". "Best" is subjective, of course, and such requests tend to simply attract little more than links to responders' favorite apps.

Comment: Thanks - I have edited the question, and also added a tag for Adobe Reader (in case there is a functionality in the app that I missed).

Comment: I've looked for such functionality for over a year, w/o success;
I've emailed Adobe about the reduced functionality of their PDF
reader under Android and emailed the developers of the main office
suites for Android (Officesuite, Kingsoft, Polaris, etc.) suggesting
such a feature, all to no avail so far. More such requests might
have some effect.
Otherwise, within 1-2 years we'll be able to dual boot our tablets under
Linux and use a Linux-based PDF presenter (acroread, evince, okular, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find a "pure" presentation mode in Aldiko, Acroread 11.7.1, 
APV, MuPDF, PDFViewer and several others I tried.

I finally settled with [Perfect Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rookiestudio.perfectviewer) and its [Perfect Viewer PDF plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rookiestudio.perfectviewer.pdfplugin). 
Extensive (excessive?!) customisation options, and you can:

1. Disable transitions
2. Drastically simplify what touch actions are allowed (simple tap on left/right part of screen, disable menu in the center, enable pinch zoom, add long-tap to reset zoom, ...).

Comment: Thanks - this is fantastic, indeed, "perfect". You can turn off the menu button at the top as well. It took me a while to figure out how to use the Kensington "PresentAir" presenter that I have with the app: When the presenter is connected, Android seems to regard it as a keyboard, and disables the on-screen keyboard. The app, however, requires the presenter to be connected to autodetect the key in question, but also requires a "description" in order to save the hardware button. But switching keyboards turns off the app!

Comment: ... However, it turns out that pressing the "stop" button on the remote registers as a "b". So I was able to enter a description of "b", save the command, turn off the remote, and then edit the description using the on-screen keyboard. A bit awkward, but that is more the remote's / Android's problem (and it may be that I was being silly in not finding anywhere to turn on both the on-screen keyboard and remote). Now that this is configured, the app seems to do absolutely everything that I want from it. Wonderful solution!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and had to try out a bunch of apps. In addition to what  you were looking for, I was also interested in the possibility to add comments during the presentation using the s-pen of my galaxy note. All the apps listed below support full page view, so there are in principle an options for presentations.

**Moon Reader Pro**

This is an excellent ebook reader. You have to pay for the full version, since the free version wont support pdf display. You can select full-page mode. By default there is no transition effect. You can also annotate while viewing. The pdf quality is very good and I have not seen any lags. Tons of options.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp

**Aldiko Book Reader**

Also a very good ebook reader that supports pdfs. Very much the same as the Moon reader, but it wont allow annotations. Also Moon reader has more options. The main advantage is that this reader is free. So try this one out first.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aldiko.android

**Acrobat Reader FoxIt and FoxIT Mobile PDF lit**

Both viewers are fast and allow annotations, but you cannot turn off the page transitions. Very annoying for presentations. Both apps are free.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxit.mobile.pdf.lite

**PDF Viewer**

This viewer was first slow, but one can change the options such that it performs okay. It has no page transitions, but it wont allow you to annotate. Free.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=the.pdfviewer3

Comment: Thanks - I actually tried Aldiko before, but either missed the option of turning off page transitions, or this has been added since then. In any case, it's very helpful - perfect!

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions - I think sneumann's new answer (Perfect Viewer) now provides a perfect answer to my query, hence I have changed this to be the accepted answer, so as to make it easier for others to find. Thanks for understanding!

Answer (score 2):

Try [XODO](https://www.xodo.com/).

I found this question because I was looking for exactly this.  Since the question was asked, some new apps are available, so I thought I'd share one that definitely works (it has an option to disable animations).  It also seems to have nice annotation tools.  Good enough to use in a classroom I'm thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Since there haven't been any responses, I'll record the solution that I have come up with so far, in case anyone else is interested. It is not quite perfect yet, so further answers / comments are certainly appreciated.

- **APV PDF Viewer** has options that allow you to disable the visible zoom buttons, lock the horizontal scroll, increase the distance between pages, and bind the Up/Down and Left/Right keys to page up/down.

Setting these options, position the page in the middle of the screen. Touching the screen right or left will forward a page, but if you are not careful, it will still lead to moving the page around. However, if you use a bluetooth remote (as I do) to forward the page, this isn't a problem and it works pretty well.

- **ezPDF Reader** does not seem to work for what I had in mind, as it does not seem to have an option that shows a 4x3 slide in full (with black borders on the sides). On the other hand, it should be possible to compose the beamer slides in *16x9-mode*, and then I think there are enough options to make this feasible. I haven't tested this yet, as I haven't yet spent any time on thinking what the best layout is for 16x9 slides. In the long run, this seems likely to be the best option.

Comment: I am interested in doing exactly the same thing (show Beamer slides on my tablet). The closest solution I've found is Radaee PDF...BEFORE the latest update (that is, version 4.2.2 works fairly well; the new update, not at all).  I'd be interested to know of any other solutions you've found.  What you suggest what APV PDF doesn't work for me (the pages get misaligned, no matter how I position it).

Answer (score 0):

hi i was reading for the solution of this problem, and i found about adobe reader X for android, in this version of adobe exist an option that allows user view the pdf in presentation mode, here i leave an extract of the information i found from [this link](http://blogs.adobe.com/readermobile/2010/11/18/introducing-adobe-reader-x-for-android)

Fit-to-Screen viewing mode

For those users who like to look at PDF documents one page at a time, Reader X introduces a new “Fit-to-Screen” viewing mode in addition to the earlier Continuous Scroll mode.  This mode is especially useful if you’re reading presentations.  Use the “View Mode” menu option to switch to this mode.

While in Fit to Screen mode, you can navigate across pages in two ways:

1 Tap on the ‘hot zones’ near the left and right of the screen to take you to the previous or next page respectively,

2 Swipe the screen horizontally towards the left or right to navigate to the next or previous page respectively."

Comment: Is this different from the functionality that I mention in my original question? In that functionality, unfortunately there is an animation for the page transition, which makes it unsuitable for beamer presentations with 'reveals'. I have not found an option to turn this off.

Answer (score 0):

[Write on PDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.spdfnote) by Samsung meets all the requirements very well.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't tried presenting from a phone / tablet for a while, but out of interest - does this only run on Samsung devices?